# Getting element not interactable: https://saucelabs.com/ has no size and location

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error** element not interactable: https://saucelabs.com/ has no size and location** when I click on hamburger menu and then click anyoption from submenu I tried work around but its not working

I am using selinium with java andd this is my code that I am writting and getting error

```
package codeclass;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class assign1code {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("user-name"));
        email.sendKeys("standard_user");
        WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]"));
        password.sendKeys("secret_sauce");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
        //identify menu

        WebElement n=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button"));
        // object of Actions with method moveToElement

        Actions a=new Actions(driver);

        a.moveToElement(n).perform();
        //identify sub-menu element

        WebElement m= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/a[2]"));
        a.moveToElement(m).click().perform();

        //driver.quit();

    }
}
```

I tried above code and it should open hamburger menu and should be able to click option from submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when you click the hamburger menu, it takes a moment to open so you need to add a wait. The script runs so fast that it clicks the right element but it's still going through the open animation so isn't able to be interacted with/clicked.

I've updated some of your locators to more consistently use IDs when available but the code below is working.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("user-name")).sendKeys("standard_user");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("secret_sauce");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("react-burger-menu-btn")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//nav/a[text()='About']"))).click();
```

Comment: @jffc I am wondering from where did you get this xpath of about button in last line of code. Because the xpath I am getting for about button is this //*[@id="about_sidebar_link"] and using this xpath I am not navigating to the next page. Can you please tell me.

Comment: I don't use the devtools Copy > Copy XPath, etc. I handcraft all my locators based on experience.